# PUT AJAX api climatempo retornando erro CORS

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

Olá, estou tendo problemas ao realizar um PUT em AJAX com a api do clima tempo, meu código é esse :

```
var URL = 'http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api-manager/user-token/TOKEN/locales';

$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType:  'application/json',
    data: {'localeId': '3477'},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("sucess?");
    }
});
}
```

o erro que me retorna é esse:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

a documentação da api:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você substituiu o valor do TOKEN na sua URL?

Comment: sim, substitui, apenas não coloquei ele aqui!

Comment: Verifica no seu acesso, em tokens, se o CORS está desabilitado para o seu projeto.